# Sinatra app on Passenger can't find Rack (using RVM)

Tags: sinatra, passenger, rvm, rack

I've been fighting with a staging server for this Sinatra app for two days. I'm getting pretty frustrated. The latest pothole is a Ruby error handed up by Passenger:

> no such file to load -- rack

The nginx.conf file shows which Ruby we're using, and where Passenger is located:

> ```
> passenger_root /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/passenger-3.0.5;
> passenger_ruby /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby;
> ```

OK, so that's Ruby 1.9.2 for us.

The vhost configuration includes:

> ```
> root /var/www/staging-proweb/current/rack/public;
> passenger_enabled on;
> rack_env          staging;
> ```

and the rackup file has:

> ```
> require 'rubygems'
> require 'sinatra'
> require 'myapp1.rb'
>
> run Sinatra::Application
> ```

which then sends us to the `myapp1.rb` file, which includes

> ```
> require 'rubygems'
> require 'rack'
> require 'sinatra'
> ```

...and I assume the sinatra require is what's calling for rack.

The gem's there:

> ```
> ~$ which ruby
> /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby
> ~$ gem list rack
>
> *** LOCAL GEMS ***
>
> rack (1.2.2)
> rack-flash (0.1.1)
> ```

The error seems to be in a file in the RVM directory, judging from the first three lines of the stack trace:

> ```
> 0 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb   36  in `require'
> 1 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb   36  in `require'
> 2 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/passenger-3.0.5/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb  219 in `load_rack_app'
> ```

What should I try next? I'm pretty stumped at this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the issue was with the `passenger_ruby` configuration value. RVM provides a wrapper to set up the appropriate environment for that Ruby (including the gems), so the `passenger_ruby` line should have read

> ```
>     passenger_ruby /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.2-p180/ruby;
> ```

With that in place, we seem to be up and running.

Comment: in passenger 3.0 this is `PassengerRuby`

Comment: This is Passenger 3.0.5. In Apache, you are right, [it is `PassengerRuby`](http://modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#PassengerRuby). In Nginx, [it is `passenger_ruby`](http://modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#_passenger_ruby_lt_filename_gt).